# Laravel 5 Route::group with public variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have some code like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'dashboard'],function(){        
    Route::get('addnew',function(){
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('username','=',session('username'))->first();
        $data = array('level' => $user->level, 'name' => $user->name,'email' => $user->email);
        return view('layout.addnew')->with($data);
    });
    Route::get('load',function(){
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('username','=',session('username'))->first();
        $data = array('level' => $user->level, 'name' => $user->name,'email' => $user->email);
        return view('layout.load')->with($data);
    });
});
```

But it don't work when i use public variable like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'dashboard'],function(){

    $user = DB::table('users')->where('username','=',session('username'))->first();
    $data = array('level' => $user->level, 'name' => $user->name,'email' => $user->email);

    Route::get('addnew',function(){        
        return view('layout.addnew')->with($data);
    });
    Route::get('load',function(){        
        return view('layout.load')->with($data);
    });
});
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you're using a Closure, you need to explicitly grant access to the variables, as they are outside of the context of the function. You do this with the "use" function.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'dashboard'],function(){

    $user = DB::table('users')->where('username','=',session('username'))->first();
    $data = array('level' => $user->level, 'name' => $user->name,'email' => $user->email);

    Route::get('addnew',function() use($data) {        
        return view('layout.addnew')->with($data);
    });
    Route::get('load',function() use($data) {        
        return view('layout.load')->with($data);
    });
});
```